# How to store data into multiple tables in Joomla?

Tags: mysql, joomla, components, transactions

I am writing a component and I have a scenerio of storing data into multiple tables with One-To-Many relationship.

Master table is **Student** and Child table is **Student_Subjects**.
One student can select multiple subjects.

I want to store the data in **Student_subject** table with student.  Data is submitted from one form where user will be created and subjects will be selected.

Currently I am using **JTable Class**.

Is there any way to run a **transaction query** to store the data in both tables?
If Yes, then how can i get the student id (auto generated) store it into Student_Subject using the same transaction query batch?

Please guide.
Example with code is highly appreciated and needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to run that simultaneously? You can run 2 queries to do this. First insert your "Student" like so:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();
```

Then get the id of the last inserted element like so:

```
$student_id = $db->insertid();
```

Now that you have the master id you can do your next insert.